# multi [] array input insert php sql

Tags: php, mysqli

Here is my input form-

```
<input type="text" multiple name="name[]">  
<input type="text" multiple name="mobile[]"> 
<input type="text" name="invoice_no">
```

Here is php script for mySQL insert which i've tried-

```
$name=mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['name']);
$mobile=mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['mobile']);
$invoice_no=mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['invoice_no']);


foreach($mobile as $a => $b){

$sql="INSERT INTO `customer` (`name`, `mobile`, `invoice_no`)
VALUES('$name[$a]', '$mobile[$a]', '$invoice_no')";

}

if ($con->query($sql) === TRUE) {
echo "Success";
} else {
echo("Error: " . mysqli_error($con));
}
```

I'm trying to insert name[] and mobile[] array as separate row along with invoice_no which is fixed data. What is the way to do that?

Comment: my mistake! edited.

Comment: you use `mysqli_real_escape_**string**` on `$_POST['name']` an array. you also only run the query once outside the loop, so only the last one will actually insert. better to concatenate the values for one querry

Comment: In `$sql` declaration, replace `$mobile[$a]` by `${mobile[$a]}` (same for `name`)

Comment: Its only inserting last row using ${$mobile[$a]} and also removing mysqli_real_escape_string

Comment: it only inserts the last row, because (as i said above) you only run the query once outside of the loop, instead of inside of the loop for every array item

Answer (score 1):

You need to bring your string escaping into the loop - as @smith pointed out, mysqli_real_escape_string should be applied to a string, not an array. Also, you are only making a query which will insert a single set of values, instead of one which will insert all values. So you can either bring the execution of the query into the loop, or build a query which will insert all rows at once. The latter is the most efficient:

```
$invoice_no = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['invoice_no']);
$sql = "INSERT INTO `customer` (`name`, `mobile`, `invoice_no`) VALUES ";
$values = array();
foreach ($_POST['mobile'] as $key => $value) {
    $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['name'][$key]);
    $mobile = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $value);
    $values[] = "('$name', '$mobile', '$invoice_no')";
}
$sql .= implode(',', $values);
if ($con->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "Success";
} else {
    echo("Error: " . mysqli_error($con));
}
```

Note that to avoid a possible injection attack, you really should use prepared statements. See the manual on [mysqli_prepare](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) to see how to use them.

Comment: your query concatenation is a little wrong, you dont want to add `VALUES` multiple times, and your missing a comma between each values set